# DI (unity) error only manifests itself after publishing to Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, azure, dependency-injection, azure-web-app-service

I have an app that we are slowly trying to migrate to Azure's Resource Manager model.  Last Friday I published the main web app to an App Service. And when I tested it in a browser after publishing, it loaded just fine, I could log in, etc.

Then, over the weekend, it occurred to me that I had published from the wrong branch.  So this morning, I came in, changed branches in VS, and re-published.  This time, when I tested the app in a browser, it immediate threw an error.

```
[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Response.Controllers.LogOnController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
```

I've seen this error before.  It's a Dependency Injection error.  The app uses Unity for D.I.  The thing is, I can fire up this branch on my local dev box straight out of VS with no problem.

To trouble shoot, I deleted the entire web app in Azure, and re-created it.  Then, I reverted VS back to the original branch that I published on Friday, and re-published from that same branch.

I get the same error.  In other words, what worked on Friday now throws this DI error on Monday.  Nothing has changed.  I've looked in the Global.asax file, and the dependency that the error mentions is registered.  I have no idea what's going on, but I think the actual error might be a red herring.

And again, everything works just fine when running on my local dev box doing a debug from VS.  And the same app runs fine with published to our (soon-to-be-old) server on RackSpace.

You can see the error here:

http://response-web-toyota-staging.azurewebsites.net/LogOn

Answer (score 0):

Well, for what it's worth, I solved this by ftp'ing into the App Service, and manually clearing out all files inside of the 'site' directory.  Then I (again) deleted the App Service, re-published, and voila.  Now it works again.

I would have thought that deleting the App Service would have done the same thing, but I guess not.

Weird.